# Automatic screenshot implementation taking multiple screenshots

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, hook, messagebox

I have implemented screenshot feature for my application which take screenshots when ever a warning or error message come up using hook.

```
HHOOK hhokCBTProc = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK pfnCBTMsgBoxHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_DESTROYWND)
    {
         TakeScreenshot(); // function call for screenshot.
    }

    return (CallNextHookEx(hhokCBTProc, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}

int SVAfxMessageBox(int textCode, UINT nType, UINT nIDHelp)
{
     if (IsScreenshotAllowed)
     {
    // set hook to center the message box that follows))
         hhokCBTProc = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, 
                            pfnCBTMsgBoxHook, 
                            0, GetCurrentThreadId());
     }

     nType = CheckIfLangIsRTL() ? (MB_RTLREADING | MB_RIGHT | nType) : nType;
     int res = AfxMessageBox(textCode, nType, nIDHelp);

     if (IsScreenshotAllowed)
     {
          // remove the hook
          UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhokCBTProc); 
     }

     return res;
}
```

Problem here is the hook executed more than once and taking multiple screen shots (even before warning message appears) before taking the actual one. Should I need to add something more to this condition "nCode == HCBT_DESTROYWND" so that it take screenshot only once?

Comment: You got the hook for the thread. can you check if there are any other windows being owned by the thread? It basically hooks all windows that are under thread control. May you might be receiving the message form other windows which you don't know.

Comment: Um, have a variable that says whether a screen shot has already been taken?

Comment: @RaymondChen: I need to take the screenshot either when messagebox come up or been disposed away. But the mentioned condition in the code is getting satisfied even before the messagebox appears. So setting a flag won't work here.

Comment: For the "before", why not take the screen shot in the main function before calling AfxMessageBox? Now there's only one screen shot that the callback needs to take. Note also that the callback is called for every window that is destroyed, including child windows, windows potentially unrelated to your application, etc. You need to add logic to determine which window destruction is the one you want to capture.